# Ghost current in 3-way light swtich

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, multiway-switch

I have a 3-way light switch in my hallway with 2 light bulbs. I canceled one of the bulbs (I don't necessarily need 2 lights) and install an LED light on the other. Now, when I'm turning off the the light from the switch, LED light doesn't turn off completely, there is still a very weak light (definitely noticeable in dark) coming from it. Initially I thought there's a problem in one of the switches, I took both of them out and connected the hot cables by hand to check the issue and it was still there.

Here's a diagram of my setup:
[image: S1 and S2 are the switches]

When I don't connect any cables in first switch (S1), I don't measure any current in any of the cables in switch 2 (S2). If I connect the live cable to S1-A, then I measure normal current in S2-A, but also weak current in S2-B and S2-C although the ends of those cables are naked and not touching each other.

When I connect replace the LED lamp with a CFL bulb, it's not effected from the weak current, i.e. when I turn it off, there's no light coming (unlike the LED, where a weak light is still emitted).

So my questions are:

1. Is the weak current in S2-B and S2-C are ghost current and what's the cause of it?
2. Could it be dangerous if I continue using CFL bulb (ignoring the weak current)?
3. How can I fix it?

Comment: Where do the neutral wires go and where does power come from?  Normally they are a third  wire in the cable to the switches.  Also, plese don't say current when you mean voltage.  They are totally different things, at least in the sense that "weight" and "speed" are different things.

Comment: Sorry for my language, I'm a layperson. Power is coming from the "Live" cable which I assume is connected to the box somehow (?) and I'm not sure where the neutral cables are going. I just figured the second cable near the light bulb must be neutral. About the weak current, what I mean is when I touch with a testing screwdriver it lights up very weakly, whereas for the hot cable it lights up normally. So I guess this means there's some voltage and when the LED light is connected there's some current (I hope that's the correct terminology).

Answer (score 2):

You're getting electro-magnetic transmission between the two travelers (A and B in your diagram). This is common and is more apparent with LED lights and highly sensitive multi-meters which will react to low level or phantom voltage.
Nothing to be concerned about but if the low level glow bothers you you might want to switch back to the CFL.

Comment: It's really more of an *electrostatic* effect, but yes, the two travelers do couple to each other slightly

Answer (score 2):

It's capacitive coupling between the wires between the two switches,
this allows a small amount of electric current to make a side-run around the open switch contacts.  This small current is enough to cause some CFLs to flash periodically and some LED fixtures to glow dimly. and to trigger non-contact voltage detectors.

It can be cured by adding a lighting capacitor in parallel with the light fixture, providing a path to neutral sufficient to pass most of the ghost current rendering to voltage at the outlet too low to activate the lamp.

Comment: I'm sorry. Your 2nd paragraph makes no sense to me. Can you explain further, or perhaps re-word? Perhaps a schematic would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason you may be getting ghost current is if you have a lighted switch